# How to move a question that was closed for being off-topic to the correct site (and unlock it so more answers can be posted)?

Tags: support, status-completed, off-topic

I posted a very popular [security-related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/524587/what-would-you-do-if-you-realized-your-email-hosting-provider-could-see-your-pas) on Server Fault yesterday.

Barely 12 hours (but 650 views) later, and it had already been locked from receiving any more responses- as it was off-topic for Server Fault.

It was a good question, just off-topic. How can I migrate it to IT Security where it belongs- so that people can continue to contribute to it?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

I tried to flag it- but I couldn't see the option anywhere:

[image]

Comment: Flag it and explain. If the mod handling that flag agrees, he will migrate.

Comment: I don't see a "flag" option.

Comment: I can't either, sorry about that. Must be related to the lock.  Anyway, a mod certainly will see the question here and chime in.

Comment: Won't it be a dupe of [this](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5813/am-i-wrong-to-believe-that-passwords-should-never-be-recoverable-one-way-hash) question if it gets migrated?

Comment: It's true that they are similar- however my question is focusing on what action we need to take (if any), given that they know our users' passwords. I am trying to establish if I am right in considering it a valid reason to change provider- or if that practice is so ubiquitous among cheaper web hosts that we may as well stay with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I threw a lock on this because it's semi-off-topic (it's really about your provider being a bit of a dingus from a security standpoint, not the actual administration of a system you control ; on the other hand the answers are somewhat useful to sysadmins, and the answers are really good ones).
As a general rule I don't look at the age of questions when I make those decisions - I try to only look at content.

Since this is in a gray area (and it's a "young" question) reopening it isn't a problem.
My personal preference is for it to stay here because it's interesting (though certainly it would benefit from input from the [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/) folks too).

Comment: Thanks for reviewing the lock- more quality answers are sure to follow.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I agree that it should stay here, but in future, I reserve the right to Lock it if it generates off-topic comments/answers.